# Where to call [self addSubView]?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a custom view to which I need to add a couple of subviews programmatically. Which is the best place to create and add these subviews? [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23) say:

> If your view class manages one or more integral subviews, do the following: Create those subviews during your view’s initialization sequence.

This is a bit unclear to me. Should I handle that in `initWithFrame`, `initWithCoder` or somewhere else?

Note that I'm not talking about controllers here, this is a View that needs to initialize itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`initWithFrame` is the method you call to create a UIView programmatically, while `initWithCoder` is called when a UIView is instanciated from a XIB.

So it all depends on how you're going to create your containing view.
A way to cover all cases :

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])){
         [self setUpSubViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
         [self setUpSubViews];//same setupv for both Methods
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setUpSubViews
{
     //here create your subviews hierarchy
}
```

Comment: An alternative being to create your views (container & subviews) from a single NIB.

Answer (score 4):

Do the following: take the method whichever is the designated initializer for your view. That is, it's the most configureable (i. e. most arguments) init... method that every other initializer calls. For example, it can be -initWithFrame:, as most commonly. Then implement this method as follows:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // add new views here, for example:
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: No problem, can you please acept if it really helped?

Comment: I've accepted another answer since it provides more "reference" code. I'd accept yours as well if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Generally , you should create the view and [self addSubView] in viewdidload/viewwillappear of the parent view controller if you want to show the view all the time. You can also set it hidden if you wih. In some other scenario like you want to show a view on a button click or some other actions, you should add subviews accordingly.

Comment: Please read more carefully! He is talking about a view that needs to create/add its own subviews. This in completely unrelated to view controllers!

Answer (score 0):

By integral, they mean either important or massive.  viewDidLoad works just fine, but for really big, or important stuff, initialization methods are the way to go.